# schema.org structure for more than one ebook

Tags: schema.org, microdata, json-ld

I want sell more than one ebook on my site. But all ebooks are in one package for a specific price. I dont know, how i must setup the schema.org. My first creation look like this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "mainEntity":{
          "@type": "Book",
          "author": "www.example.com",
          "bookFormat": "https://schema.org/EBook",
          "fileFormat": "application/pdf"
          "image": "example.jpg",
          "inLanguage": "English",
          "name": "Example",
          "numberOfPages": "20",
          "genre": "Example",
          "description": "Description example",
          "keywords": "Keyword example",
          "offers": {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "price": "1.00",
            "priceCurrency": "USD",
            "category": "",
            "availability": "https://schema.org/OnlineOnly",
            "availableDeliveryMethod": "http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#DeliveryModeDirectDownload"
          },
          "publisher": "www.example.com",
        }
}
</script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your product seems a **grouped product** of **downloadable products**, which are enlisted eBooks.

There are two ways to implement a list format for your structured data:

1. **Summary page + multiple full details pages**
2. **A single, all-in-one-page list**

If the page has **full details of each eBook in the list** prefer `A single, all-in-one-page list` else if the page has **short description of each eBook in the list** use `Summary page + multiple full details pages` [as described in here.](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/carousel)

Regards,
**Vivek**